# How do i resolve E[AB], given E[A]=0 and E{b]=0, var(A) = 4 and correlation(A,B)== -0.5?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, correlation

The question is:
Let k be an unspecifed constant, and suppose we are given that A;B;C
are three random variables that satisfy
C = (kA + 3B)2;E[A] = E[B] = 0; var(A) = 4; var(C) = 16; correlation(A;B) = -0.5:
Determine the value of k that minimizes E[C].

I have determined that E[A]2 =4 and E[C] = 4k^2 +6k(E[AB])+ 9(E[B^2]). Is anyone able to help me how to find out what is the value of E[AB] and E[B^2]? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $-0.5 = cor(A, B) = \frac{cov(A, B)}{\sqrt{var[A]var[B]}} = \frac{E[AB] - E[A]E[B]}{\sqrt{var[A]var[B]}} = \frac{E[AB]}{\sqrt{4var[B]}} \Rightarrow E[AB] = -\sqrt{var[B]}$.

Now, you need to optimize a function (which is a convex quadratic function, so the minima exists)

$$
E[C] = 4k^2 + 6k(-\sqrt{var[B]}) + 9var[B],
$$

where $k$ is the function argument, and $var[B]$ is an unknown constant and is treated as a parameter. Then,

$$
\frac{d}{dk}E[C] = \frac{d}{dk}\left(4k^2 + 6k(-\sqrt{var[B]}) + 9var[B]\right) = 8k - 6\sqrt{var[B]} = 0 \Leftrightarrow k = \frac{3}{4}\sqrt{var[B]}.
$$

$k$ depends on the $var[B]$.

Comment: Is there any way to use Var(c)=16 and find out what is the value of var[b]?

Comment: For me, it doesn't seem feasible. Are you sure that the problem says that $var[C] = 16$, and not $var[B] = 16$?

Comment: Yes, the problem definitely states var[c]=16 and I have been trying to obtain var[b] from var[c] but it is not working out